# convert yyyymmdd into yyyy/mm/dd in sybase

Tags: sybase

Date in table1 is in 'yyyymmdd' format but date in table2 is in 'yyyy/mm/dd' format. and I want to insert the data directly from table1 into table2. 
For ex. Date Format in table1 is '20130813' and date format in table2 is '08/13/2013 12:00:00.000 AM' . Here 12:00:00.000 AM is default timestamp. Can you please help in converting the date from '20130813' to '08/13/2013 12:00:00.000 AM' in sybase ?

Comment: Most databases use the 12:00:00.000 AM time when you initialize a date. Check the Sybase manual. Also, what datatypes are your dates in table1 and table2?

Comment: table1 it is date and for table2 it is datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not having Sybase currently installed, but you could try

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '20131031')
```

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA SELECT CONVERT(datetime, TABLEBCOLUMN)
```

Comment: 10/31/2013 12:00:00 AM --> this is what your select gave in Sybase. The millisecond is missing.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try:

```
 select cast(dateformat('20131031','yyyymmdd') as datetime)
```

The advantages are:

- Not relying on implicit conversion to date
- CONVERT function is not ANSI SQL

Comment: It does work in Sybase IQ 15.4. What Sybase database are you using ?

Comment: I m using Sybase ASE 11

Comment: dateformat function is not available in ASE. The Function above works in Sybase ASA and IQ